# Jackson Timestamp wrong deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, timestamp, deserialization

I have a custom objectmapper-class:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;


public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";

public CustomObjectMapper() {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    this.setDateFormat(df);
}
```

and a unit test:

```
@Test
public void testSerialization() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException  {

    String timestamp = "2019-02-12T07:53:11+0000";
    CustomObjectMapper customObjectMapper = new CustomObjectMapper();
    Timestamp result = customObjectMapper.readValue(timestamp, Timestamp.class);
    System.out.println(result.getTime());

}
```

The junit-test gives me "2019".

I tried to use a customTimestampDeserializer:

```
public class CustomJsonTimestampDeserializer extends
    JsonDeserializer<Timestamp> {

@Override
public Timestamp deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser,
        DeserializationContext deserializationcontext) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

    String date = jsonparser.getText(); //date is "2019"
    JsonToken token = jsonparser.getCurrentToken(); // is JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            CustomObjectMapper.DATE_FORMAT);
    try {
        return new Timestamp(simpleDateFormat.parse(date).getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

What am I doint wrong? It seems like jackson thinks the timestamp-string is an integer ans stops parsing it after 2019.

Comment: Do you use `Timestamp` from `java.sql`?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are two problems with this approach.

First of all, there is a suspicious import statement:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
```

`org.codehaus` is a predecessor of current `com.fasterxml`. It's not clear if it was used intentionally, but `ObjectMapper`'s import should be

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

Second, a Timestamp cannot be read directly from a plain String like this

```
String timestamp = "2019-02-12T07:53:11+0000";
```

`ObjectMapper` expects a JSON string. So if it were

```
{ "timestamp": "2019-02-12T07:53:11+0000" }
```

and a wrapping class

```
class TimestampWrapper {

  private Timestamp timestamp;
  // getter + setter for timestamp
}
```

then the test sequence will execute properly:

```
String timestamp = "{ \"timestamp\": \"2019-02-12T07:53:11+0000\" }";
CustomObjectMapper customObjectMapper = new CustomObjectMapper();
TimestampWrapper result = customObjectMapper.readValue(timestamp, TimestampWrapper.class);
System.out.println(result.getTimestamp());
```

*update:*

Or, without using a dedicated wrapper class, it can be deserialized from an JSON array:

```
String timestamp = "[ \"2019-02-12T07:53:11+0000\" ]";
CustomObjectMapper customObjectMapper = new CustomObjectMapper();
Timestamp[] result = customObjectMapper.readValue(timestamp, Timestamp[].class);
System.out.println(result[0]);
```

Comment: { "timestamp": "2019-02-12T07:53:11+0000" } <- This solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might be that Jackson is not recognizing `Timestamp` as a date type and so no relying on the `DateFormat`

Can you try to use a `Java.util.Date` instead of `Timestamp`?